# jquery mobile fixed header & footer are not moving with the page to the right in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on jquery mobile and i'm using side panel to show navigation menu.
I'm having problems using fixed elements and side panel on Android. I have a fixed header and a left side panel but when I show the panel (reveal animation) the fixed header is not moving with the page to the right, it keeps its position over the panel. This is only happening on Android, iOS is working fine.

Please tell me what i have to do so that my Fixed Elements(Header & Footer) also work same as iOS

Comment: Hi, I think you wouldn't get an answer, because you didn't provide an example link. It depends on how you implemented sidebar menu opening an of course other things.